# t-sql matching words when insert with data on a table

Tags: sql, t-sql, pattern-matching

I have a web application through a user can upload an Excel file with some destination. When the file is uploaded, I read the rows and insert them in a SQL Server database.
On the SQL Server I have to do a matching of the destination with a list of destinations in a table. As the list of destinations in the database is the reference, matching must be accurate.
Here is an example of a destination from database and a destination uploaded by the user (among which must be made to match):

- from database: United Kingdom - Mobile - O2
- Uploaded by user: United Kingdom - O2 Mobile

What is the best way to make more accurate matching?

Comment: Please provide more information and more sample data. From your example it could be pretty straight-forward to do the matching, for example just split the second part at the space character. But I assume the situation is more complex since you asked a question here, so please provide more info.

Comment: Would 02 Kingdom Mobile - United also be considered a valid match ?

Comment: @t-clausen.dk - No, 02 Kingdom Mobile is not a valid match. The country name should be UK or United Kingdom. We have a matching pattern for countries also, but this is one is working. All I need is to match the other two words (Mobile and the provider).

Comment: @David Abrahamsson - what data you need? You're saying we can use split the second part, but if the country's name have space is a problem.

Comment: It is very possible to split the database data and the input data. However it will be a slow query, you should consider changing your database design and/or force the user to provide proper input in some sort of form, maybe using dropdown

Comment: As I know DQS (Data Quality Services) provides solution for that kind of problems. You can also use Integration Services and Fuzzy lookup component for that. It's a large topic though. But I can't imagine how to solve that task with simple query, if you don't have fixed bisuness rules on your initial data.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk - i can't provide a dropdown - the comparison when I'm trying to insert the info from a xls file (read row by row). This is why it's hard. I think you can't tell to a client of your client "please send me a file formated as I want" - this is the case here. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this problem can be solved using T-SQL only. Unfortunately T-SQL has no good algorithms for fuzzy matching. Soundex is not very relevant, full text search neither for this problem.

I would recommend a very good library written in C# http://anastasiosyal.com/post/2009/01/11/Beyond-SoundEx-Functions-for-Fuzzy-Searching-in-MS-SQL-Server. It implements a lot of string metric algorithms like and can be imported as CLR functions in SQL Server. Can have performance issues for a large amount of data.

I also can recommend, especially because you import data, to create a SSIS package. In a package you can use Fuzzy Lookup Transformation block to identify similarities:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163731.aspx.
I use it to identify duplicates, based on similarity, in a table with more than 1 million records.
Also in both cases you will have to run some tests in order to define the percent of similarity for an accurate matching in case of your business.

Comment: SSIS cannot be used - you have to have the Enterprise edition of SQL Server 2012 to use Fuzzy Grouping and Lookup - see here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions.aspx (on the lower part of the table).

Answer (score 1):

I have solved lots of problems like this. Split the database data into relevant columns (Country, Device, Brand) in a temp table. Split the user input data (excel) into relevant columns (Country, Device, Brand) before you import into the database. Then import excel data into a temp table. Then you can adjust your matching anyway you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a matching algorithm. If it is by counting words that match, no matter what order they occur, here it is:

```
declare @t table(field varchar(200))
insert into @t values('United Kingdom - Mobile - O2')
declare @upload varchar(200) = ' United   Kingdom  -  O2    Mobile noise'

-- Let's find matching words, no matter in what order they are!
declare @IgnoreChars varchar(50) = char(13)+char(10)+char(9)+'-.,'
select t.field,
    MatchedWords = SUM(CASE WHEN m.WordFoundAt=0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END),
    TotalWords = COUNT(*)
from @t t
    CROSS APPLY dbo.str_split(dbo.str_translate(@upload, @IgnoreChars, REPLICATE(' ', LEN(@IgnoreChars))), ' ') w
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT WordFoundAt = CHARINDEX(w.id, t.field)) m
where w.id <> ''
group by t.field
```

Result:

field               MatchedWords    TotalWords

United Kingdom - Mobile - O2    4       5

Functions str_translate and str_split are not built-in, but I don't know how to post them here since attachments are not allowed.

Comment: I've tried your solution, but if you're changing some of the words and punctuation, the result is wrong.